# vs code , snippets, templates, quick entry of classes and attributes

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code

I apologize in advance for the question with syntactic and semantic errors, English is not my native language.

I recently started learning web development, I'm currently learning bootstrap 5 and I've come across some incomprehensible moments:

1. what are the sane snippets or templates for writing elementary constructions, for example, if I want to make an elementary container construction

```html
<div class="container">
        
</div>
```

when I try to enter cont or .cont and then press "ctrl + space" then this is not offered automatically

emmet is set, and when you type .cont a block with the class "cont" is created, which is naturally not what I need

2. Let's also assume that the i have file bootstrap.css file is connected to the project, and there are a lot of default classes in it, it happens that when I'm already in the tag, I want to register a class, and I start to enter a class, VScode behaves differently, sometimes it will show the options in the drop-down the menu, but sometimes it doesn’t show anything, what these glitches are connected with, can someone tell me how to get rid of different behavior? The IntelliSense for CSS class names in HTML extension is installed, but it doubles up in the dropdown list that VScode gives by default, and it's not clear how to disable the default behavior of VScode.
3. being in the  tag or in the  tag (link) you need to enter the data-bs-toggle attribute, the attribute is visible in the drop-down menu, and you can quickly select it, but when I get into quotes, the attribute value can be system will offer or maybe not offer, also with what it can be connected? Example data-bs-toggle="pill" , the value "pill" is not always displayed in the drop down menu and has to be searched for or entered manually.
4. for example, I am in the  tag and start typing "cla" in one case, until I press ctrl + space, the class will not be offered, in the other case, literally further in the "a" tag, when typing "cla", almost immediately it is proposed to automatically make a class ="" (empty), again in this case VScode again behaves differently, all other things being equal, at these moments there are no reinstallation of extensions or other settings

Windows 10, projects and the system are all on a good ssd nvme, there should be no problems with loading a text file. All these questions came to me while studying Bootstrap 5.

I would be grateful for advice from experienced people, with the organization of the process of automating code entry. Maybe there are good extensions that I don’t know about yet, maybe the code editor chose the wrong one, maybe there are editors where you don’t need to install any extensions and everything works out of the box, intuitively?